# How to limit search scope to accounts, contacts, and opportunities?

Tags: search, page-layout

Attempting to limit the search scope drop down to accounts, contacts, and opportunities.

Here's a pick of the search I'm attempting to remove items from:

[image]

**Is this possible, and if so, how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to remove the items by going to Setup > Users > Roles > Object Permissions, then per object removing permission to view the object. For information on [removing Tasks, Events, Notes see this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/how-to-set-object-permissions-to-no-access-for-tasks-events-notes-users), and for information on [removing Users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/how-to-set-object-permissions-to-no-access-for-tasks-events-notes-users%20Tasks,%20Events,%20Notes,%20Users?) from the dropdown, [see this comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/how-to-set-object-permissions-to-no-access-for-tasks-events-notes-users%20Tasks,%20Events,%20Notes,%20Users?).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. All options can be found in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_sidebar_scope.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Please explain how the you've documentation referenced proves that it is not possible. More to the point, via the permission sets, the user in question should not have access to those items; meaning to me, it's a bug if there's not a way to address the issue. Thanks!

Comment: So, it's not completely possible, but also not completely impossible either. [See this answer for more information.](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36903/7651)