# How to set object permissions to no access for: Tasks, Events, Notes, Users?

Tags: tasks, user, event, notes, custom-profile

Within the profile settings, under object settings, then object permissions - I do not see the option to set a profiles object permissions for Tasks, Events, Notes, Users to no access. Appears that I am able to set the field level permissions, though it's unclear why there is not the option to set the object permissions to no access, if there's another place to do this, and if not, if removing access via the fields will have the same results. How to set object permissions to no access for: Tasks, Events, Notes, Users?

**Update:** In retrospect, might be worth stating the problem that resulted in this question. I am creating a barebones user and have removed links to Tasks, Events, Notes, and Users - but these object are still showing up in searchable fields by objects dropdown for the sidebar search. As I've removed object permissions from other objects, they've been removed from the dropdown, so I believe removing permissions for these objects will have the same results.

Comment: Can you contact Salesforce to enable "Organization Wide Defaults" private sharing setting for the USER object as a first means of hiding them..?

Comment: @user320: Are you saying that I need to contact SF and request that they add the `user` object to "Setup > Security Controls > Sharing Settings" and then set "Default Access" to `Private` for the `user` object? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this will allow you to hide users from each other, if you really wished your 'barebones user' not to see them. Would be great if we can learn more about the spirit of your requirements.

Comment: +1 @user320: Thanks, that's what I'll do then, since I don't know any reason why users should be able to see which others configs, beyond maybe supervisors being able to view configs of staff that report to them.

Comment: As for the spirit of my requirements, in my opinion, less "surface area" results in lower training requirements, improved security, better usability, etc. - and the first step is to create a barebones config, then layer additional "surface area" as required. Does that answer your question, or is either my reply unclear, or the intent of your question something else? Thanks!

Comment: Cheers for clarifying your approach. Sounds like good first principles. To people with existing salesforce literacy, Task / Event / Note / Attachment / FeedItem might be received as "metadata" distinct from first class citizen objects like Account / Contact / Opportunity, etc. But they can totally complicate your page layouts! :-)

Comment: @user320: In this case, the use of account, contact, opportunity happen to be the core objects that "they" want, which isn't really what I'd suggest, but if that's what they want, that's all they're going to see. As for objects, I just thought of everything as being an object, but it's pretty clear to me at this point that there are a lot of assumptions baked into SF that are not obvious; for example, that all contacts require accounts. Any rate, thanks for asking, and glad that I addressed your question! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks, Events and Notes all have a field named Private (data type boolean) that controls the sharing of these objects.  Users visibility would be controlled by hierarchy and entity history.  I hope that helps.

Comment: So, basically the answer is that it's only possible control the sharing of these objects, not access to objects themselves, right, or am I misunderstanding your answer? Here's an example that I just found as a result of your reference to "hierarchy" (which I believe means role hierarchy) that appears to define the [factors used to determine access to tasks and events](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm&language=en_US). _PS - good luck with your goal of becoming a SF-Dev!_